# How can I set the "forward all" feature for an extension on cisco call manager with PHP?

Tags: php, call, cisco, cisco-axl

I am using the AXL API with PHP, and I want to make an application that allows the user to set the forward to voicemail feature on cisco call manager for an extension. However, I cannot find a good tutorial or documentation on the updateLine() function. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updateLine() function takes data as argument. Format of data to set forward all to voicemail is:

```
$data = array("pattern"=>$extension,"callForwardAll"=>array("forwardToVoiceMail"=true))
```

Howto articles
https://developer.cisco.com/site/axl/learn/how-to/index.gsp

Create php soap client https://developer.cisco.com/site/axl/learn/how-to/axl-php-primer.gsp

All available functions with information on data structure required https://developer.cisco.com/site/axl/develop-and-test/documentation/latest-version/axl-soap.gsp

Comment: I try that, but then I get this error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'AXLAPI.wsdl' : failed to load external entity "AXLAPI.wsdl"

Comment: Ignore that last comment I figured it out. The code worked, thank you for being so detailed and for the links!